# Modify a string in an array from a starting point

Tags: python, arrays

I have been searching into the forum but no luck for this one, which I hope it is an easy one, basically I want to modify strings in an list starting from the 12 character for each argument. This is the list:

```
[' address 0 201.175.131.20 0', ' address 2 4.2.2.2 0', ' address 0 107.22.0.0 0.0.255.255']
```

I was expecting something like this:

```
address[0][11:] = "192.168.10.1"
```

But it says:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Any ideas how can I achieve it.

Thanks

Comment: strings are not mutable. Basically you have to create a new string and assign it to the list item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable - once created they cannot be changed - and so are strings slices, which are also strings.

You have to build a **new** string using the part of the slice that should be retained, and then replace the previous string object at index 0:

```
address[0] = address[0][:11] + "192.168.10.1" 
print address
# [' address 0 192.168.10.1', ' address 2 4.2.2.2 0', ' address 0 107.22.0.0 0.0.255.255']
```

And to replicate this across the list, use a *list comprehension*:

```
address = [s[:11] + "192.168.10.1" for s in address]
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable, but here you can update the list.

You can update your list items by creating a new string.

```
>>> lista = [' address 0 201.175.131.20 0', ' address 2 4.2.2.2 0', ' address 0 107.22.0.0 0.0.255.255']
>>> lista[0] = lista[0][:11] + "192.168.10.1"
>>> lista
[' address 0 192.168.10.1', ' address 2 4.2.2.2 0', ' address 0 107.22.0.0 0.0.255.255']
```

Alteringn your list:

```
[ip[:11] + "192.168.10.1" for ip in lista]
```

Pulling out all the ip's:

```
>>> [ip.split(" ")[3] for ip in lista]
['201.175.131.20', '4.2.2.2', '107.22.0.0']
```